# Saving a dynamic chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have created a dynamic chart and I want to export it. I find the control using the below code

```
Chart Chart_export = (Chart)chart_holder.FindControl("chart1");
```

but when I use the SaveImage method it is not found

```
Chart_export.SaveImage(exportFileName, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This did work when the chart was not dynamic.

The error message i get is - does not contain definition for SaveImage

Am i missing something ?

Comment: "Did not work" is usually a rather broad and therefore bad error description.

Comment: edited. Error I get is that there is no definition for SaveImage

Comment: Are you using the System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting namespace?

Comment: Yes I am using that namespace